# When was Darth Vader's armor designed, and how does this reflect on Palpatine's plans?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

Darth Vader's suit was fitted to Anakin Skywalker shortly after his recovery from the planet Mustafar. According to [this article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Vader%27s_armor), his armor comprised of a number of rare components, including a *Mandalorian Crush Gaunt*, a glove capable of deflecting a lightsaber, and *sith amulet* and *sith alchemy* to top it off.

Considering the rarity and uniqueness of these components and the effort that was likely required, was Darth Vader's suit designed and assembled before or after Anakin's duel on Mustafar? If it were assembled prior to the duel, then what were Chancellor Palpatine's plans for such a unique set of armor? Does it suggest that Palpatine foresaw Anakins defeat at the hands of Obi-Wan?

Comment: Probably basic suit first, upgrades later

Comment: Note that your link goes to the Legends article, meaning some if not most of the info there is not canon. [This](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vader%27s_armor) is the canon-only link, and there's no mention of the Sith Alchemy and Mandalorian stuff.

Comment: "A glove capable of deflecting a lightsaber"? Must have been the left glove :P

Comment: "Leather... full body black leather..." https://youtu.be/g0ffCICQ-bU

Comment: +1 Good question. My guess would be that Sidious had been collecting the elements over time, or inherited them from his master Plagueis. Vader's suit follows the design tradition of Sith armors after all (in Legends). Maybe Sidious saw that Vader would not survive without some additional help of Sith alchemy, despite of all the cybernetics.

Answer (score 2):

If you want answer from the Legends, Darth Plagueis had a vision of Anakin enclosed in black armor, looking like a cyborg (novel Darth Plagueis). This happened on Coruscant, when he first saw the boy being presented to Jedi Council. It is possible he told Palpatine about that, or Palpatine had a similar vision. One of the main goals of Palpatine was to turn the Chosen One to the Dark Side, therefore preventing the Prophecy about the destruction of the Sith from happening. The creation of the armor could be an important part of that, therefore preparation for the creation of the suit could then take years, although I'm not sure that Palpatine expected Anakin would lose all of his limbs.

In canon, there is no mention of suit being something special when it was created, but we know from Rogue One that Anakin/Vader could survive without it in a bacta tank. That time could be used to upgrade the armor with rare materials.